# (scipy.stats.qmc) How to do multiple randomized Quasi Monte Carlo

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I want to generate many randomized realizations of a low discrepancy sequence thanks to `scipy.stat.qmc`. I only know this way, which directly provide a randomized sequence:

```
from scipy.stats import qmc
ld = qmc.Sobol(d=2, scramble=True)
r = ld.random_base2(m=10)
```

But if I run

```
r = ld_deterministic.random_base2(m=10)
```

twice I get

```
The balance properties of Sobol' points require n to be a power of 2. 2048 points have been previously generated, then: n=2048+2**10=3072. If you still want to do this, the function 'Sobol.random()' can be used.
```

It seems like using `Sobol.random()` is discouraged from the doc.

What I would like (and it should be faster) is to first get

```
ld = qmc.Sobol(d=2, scramble=False)
```

then to generate like a 1000 scrambling (or other randomization method) from this initial series.
It avoids having to regenerate the Sobol sequence for each sample and just do scrambling.

How to that?

It seems to me like it is the proper way to do many Randomized QMC, but I might be wrong and there might be other ways.

Answer (score 0):

As the warning suggests, Sobol' is a sequence meaning that there is a link between with the previous samples. You have to respect the properties of 2^m. It's perfectly fine to use `Sobol.random()` if you understand how to use it, this is why we created `Sobol.random_base2()` which prints a warning if you try to do something that would break the properties of the sequence. Remember that with Sobol' you cannot skip 10 points and then sample 5 or do arbitrary things like that. If you do that, you will not get the convergence rate guaranteed by Sobol'.

In your case, what you want to do is to reset the sequence between the draws (`Sobol.reset`). A new draw will be different from the previous one if scramble=True. Another way (using a non scrambled sequence for instance) is to sample 2^k and skip the first 2^(k-1) points then you can sample 2^n with n<k-1.